# Question about a driver rotation expression

Tags: python, armature, transforms, drivers

so I have a character with a skirt that's rigged. The skirt is positioned much higher up than the leg so once her leg/thigh reaches a certain height, I want her skirt bone that I have set up to also start rotating. I've managed to get the matching rotation occur with drivers, but at the moment I'm trying to set up an IF statement with the intention of: if the thigh bone is rotated 30.1 degrees on the Z axis, then start rotating (it would 30.1 or *higher*). I don't know much python, I do understand the fundamentals of creating variables and then plugging them into expressions which will then be evaluated.

Here's an image of my current driver setup

[image]

I'm a bit lost at this point, I have a value Zrt that perfectly represents the thigh bone's rotation and so once Zrt reaches a value of 30.1, then the dress bone would begin it's rotation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have nothing in the `Expresion:` It's difficult to know what you've tried without seeing what you've got as the expresion. But if that IS the question, you need to make your "code" in the `Expresion:`

Comment: Closed since the basic gist is an if statement in driver expression. To be zero until 30.1 and difference after could use someting like  `0 if var < radians(30.1) else (var - radians(30.1)`   which is also `max(0, var - radians(30.1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating how much?  What about when thigh bone isn't rotated that much?

The form of a single line "If" is something like the following:

((var * constant1) * (var>(30.1 * pi/1800))) + ((var * constant2) * (1.0- var>(30.1 * pi/180)))

What that's saying:

a) If var's rotation is greater than 30.1 degrees, output var * constant1.

b) Else, output var * constant2.

Constant2 can be zero.  You can understand this by recognizing that a statement like var>n returns 1 if the statement is true and 0 if it is false.  Multiplying 1.0 - whatever instead of flipping > for <= is just style in this case, but it's style informed by the situations where the things you're measuring aren't exactly 0 or 1.

And the reason for var>(30.1*pi/180) is because, for drivers, you're working with radians, not degrees.  (Don't ask me why, it's a developer decision than I don't necessarily agree with.)

Comment: A "single line if" is called a _ternary expression_. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions The math method `radians` is also known to the driver namespace, hence  for conversion can instead use `var > radians(30.1)`   btw 2pi radians = 360 degrees so the conversion is `180 / pi`  The reason blender uses radians, as does the math module is explained somewhat here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Advantages_of_measuring_in_radians .

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the catch, fixed,  Afraid I don't see the relevance of the WP link to this particular context (are we going to calculate limits in our Python drivers?) and of course any potential advantages of radians have to be compared to advantages of degrees, and advantage of consistency considering measurements used elsewhere, but of course, this isn't the place to debate that.

Comment: Seems to be a case of "don't know why... but I disagree"  From wiki link: _"most other branches of mathematics beyond practical geometry, angles are universally measured in radians. This is because radians have a mathematical "naturalness" that leads to a more elegant formulation of a number of important results.

Most notably, results in analysis involving trigonometric functions can be elegantly stated, when the functions' arguments are expressed in radians."_   Blender leans heavily on _trigonometry and linear algebra_ Suggest this is why the `math` module also uses angles in radians.